# What's the difference between 落す and 落とす?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, readings, okurigana

Both 落す and 落とす seem to be pronounced おとす and have the same meaning. Are they variants? Different words? Is one of them technically wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The verb is usually written 落とす and one of the [official readings](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B8%B8%E7%94%A8%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7) for 落:

> **落**
> ラク、お-ちる、お-とす

<sup>One way to remember the *okurigana* is to note that the reading of the *kanji* should be short enough, i.e. the *okurigana* should be long enough, to accommodate all transitive/intransitive variants. Here, we also have おちる "to fall down", so that we have [落とす]{おとす} and [落ちる]{おちる} without having to change the reading of 落 from [落]{おと} to [落]{おち}.</sup>

That said, it is also [officially allowed](https://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kijun/naikaku/okurikana/honbun02.html) (see 「許容」 below) to shorten the *okurigana* to only the inflecting suffix (i.e. one *kana*) when the reading is unambiguous:

> ### 通則2
>
> #### 本則
>
> 活用語尾以外の部分に他の語を含む語は，含まれている語の送り仮名の付け方によって送る。(含まれている語を〔　〕の中に示す。)
>
> 〔例〕
>
> (1)　動詞の活用形又はそれに準ずるものを含むもの。
>
> 動かす〔動く〕　照らす〔照る〕
> 語らう〔語る〕　計らう〔計る〕　向かう〔向く〕
> 浮かぶ〔浮く〕
> 生まれる〔生む〕　押さえる〔押す〕　捕らえる〔捕る〕
> 勇ましい〔勇む〕　輝かしい〔輝く〕　喜ばしい〔喜ぶ〕
> 晴れやかだ〔晴れる〕
> 及ぼす〔及ぶ〕　積もる〔積む〕　聞こえる〔聞く〕
> 頼もしい〔頼む〕
> 起こる〔起きる〕　落とす〔落ちる〕
> 暮らす〔暮れる〕　冷やす〔冷える〕
> 当たる〔当てる〕　終わる〔終える〕　変わる〔変える〕　　集まる〔集める〕　定まる〔定める〕　連なる〔連ねる〕　交わる〔交える〕
> 混ざる・混じる〔混ぜる〕
> 恐ろしい〔恐れる〕
>
> (2)　形容詞・形容動詞の語幹を含むもの。
>
> 重んずる〔重い〕　若やぐ〔若い〕
> 怪しむ〔怪しい〕　悲しむ〔悲しい〕　苦しがる〔苦しい〕
> 確かめる〔確かだ〕
> 重たい〔重い〕　憎らしい〔憎い〕　古めかしい〔古い〕
> 細かい〔細かだ〕　柔らかい〔柔らかだ〕
> 清らかだ〔清い〕　高らかだ〔高い〕　寂しげだ〔寂しい〕
>
> (3)　[...]
>
> #### 許容
>
> 読み間違えるおそれのない場合は，活用語尾以外の部分について，次の(　)の中に示すように，送り仮名を省くことができる。
>
> 〔例〕　浮かぶ(浮ぶ)　生まれる(生れる)　押さえる(押える)　捕らえる(捕える)
>
> 晴れやかだ(晴やかだ)
> 積もる(積る)　聞こえる(聞える)
> 起こる(起る)　落とす(落す)　暮らす(暮す)　当たる(当る)　終わる(終る)　変わる(変る)

The [BCCWJ](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/) has

```
落とす　  1657 results
落す　　   130 results
```

but

```
落とした  1622 results
落した　  1013 results
```

Also in compound words like 落(と)し子, 落(と)し蓋, 落(と)し主, etc., the extra *kana* is a bit more likely to be dropped, although the longer version still seems to be more frequent in all cases.

```
落とし蓋   15 results
落し蓋　   12 results

落とし子   13 results
落し子　    6 results
```

### tl;dr

Safely use 落とす everywhere, but don't be surprised to see 落す or especially 落し～.