# What does 「かかと」 mean?

Tags: translation, words, particles, syntax, conjunctions

Here's my sentence. It's describing an attack.

> 強力な**かかと**落してで周囲を攻撃する

I know what everything else means but does anyone know what 「かかと」 means? I've never seen it before.

Comment: What does your dictionary say about かかと or かかと落とし? (Wait, does it really say 落してで, not 落としで?)

Comment: I used jisho.org and put the whole sentence in. So, It read the individual hiragana as a particle

Comment: こっちの辞書使ってみたら・・・http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A8%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97

Comment: Jisho.orgにも載ってましたね -> http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A8%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97

Comment: Or [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A8%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97&tbm=isch)

Answer (score 3):

かかと means a heel, and かかと落とし (or かかと落し when a okurigana is partly dropped; lit. "heel drop") is a common word that means [axe kick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGl-UfrzxNU).

See: [What's the difference between 落す and 落とす?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36568/5010)