# Is おわる ever written as "終る"?

Tags: okurigana

Is 終る ever used, or only 終わる, or is there any difference? I only ask because both are suggested when I type おわる.

Comment: It's [listed in dictionaries](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B). I don't know what else we're supposed to say to answer the question.

Comment: 「世界が終るまでは/離れることもない/そう願っていた/幾千の夜も」[「世界が**終る**までは…」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%81%8C%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8B%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E2%80%A6)

Comment: I'm familiar with Jisho, but 終る is listed under "other forms". That's the only reason I asked. If it's not used it should be listed under the "notes" section as rarely used.

Answer (score 3):

It's an uncommon variant of 終わる. For the background, read this question: [What's the difference between 落す and 落とす?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36568/5010)

Although 終る is officially "allowed" (because it was traditionally used in the past when the language was not very standardized), it looks outdated, is no longer taught at school, and may be considered wrong in exams. 終わる is always safer in modern Japanese.